# Can I use a boolean loop to find equal values btw two df cols then set df1['col1'] = df2['col2']

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iterator

I have to find the values of `df2 col1` that are equal to `df1 col1`, then replace `df1 col2` with `df2 col2` from the same row.

I've already tried `.isin()` (possibly incorrectly) and multiple conditions i.e. `if (df1['col1'] == df2['col1']) & (df1['col3'] == 'x index')`

```
i=0
for i in df1:
     if df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1']):
          df1['col2'] = df2['col2']
     else df1['col1'].isin(df3):
          df1['col2'] = df['col3']
 i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to pandas, but with Pythonic option:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame as DF


columns = ["col1", "col2"]

df1 = DF([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c")
], columns=columns)

df2 = DF([
    (4, "x"),
    (2, "y"),
    (5, "z")
], columns=columns)

for i, z in enumerate(zip(df1.col1, df2.col1, df2.col2)):
    compare_1, compare_2, value = z
    if compare_1 == compare_2:
        df1.col2[i] = value
        pass
    pass

print(df1)

#    col1 col2
# 0     1    a
# 1     2    y  <--- new value
# 2     3    c
```

Explaintaion of `enumerate`:

Enumerate generate tuple of `(index, value_from_list)`

```py
for i, value in enumerate(["x", "y", "z"]):
    print(i, value, sep=": ")

# Output:
# 0: x
# 1: y
# 2: z
```

Explaintaion of `zip`:

Zip generates tuples of each value in iterables (list, dict, etc..).

```py
abc = ["a", "b", "c"]
xyz = ["x", "y", "z"]
num = [1, 2, 3]

for one_of_abc, one_of_xyz, one_of_num in zip(abc, xyz, num):
    print(one_of_abc, one_of_xyz, one_of_num)
    pass

# Output:
# a x 1
# b y 2
# c z 3

# Alternative without unpacking

for tuple_of_items in zip(abc, xyz, num):
    print(tuple_of_items[0], tuple_of_items[1], tuple_of_items[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, if you find a solution without using loops, it is always better. In your case, finding rows that are in an other column can be solved by an inner join. Here is, I hope, a code that can solve your issue.

```py
In [1]:
## Set the exemple with replicable code
import pandas as pd

cols = ['col1', 'col2'] 
data = [[100, 150],
        [220, 240],
        [80, 60]
       ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols).set_index('col1')


cols = ['col1', 'col2'] 
data = [[111, 0],
        [220, 0],
        [80, 0]
       ]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols).set_index('col1')

## Get all the rows from df1 col1 that are in df2 col1
df_merge = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
df_merge

Out [1]:
        col2_df1    col2_df2
col1        
220     240         0
80      60          0
```

Then Do a left join to add the values from `col2 df2` to `col2 df1`

```py
In [2]:
df1 = df1.merge(df_merge, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df1.drop(axis=1, columns=['col2', 'col2_df1'], inplace=True)
df1.rename(columns={'col2_df2': 'df2'}, inplace=True)
df1

Out [2]:
    df2
col1    
100 NaN
220 0.0
80  0.0
```

Comment: Did this help ? Are you still struggling with this issue ?